# QGIS project variable in map composer template file?

Tags: qgis, qgis-variable

I need to insert project variable into **map composer file (.qpt)** for showing specific legend item. The item is a layer constructed from a URL query that I need to **dynamically change based on a project variable.**

When I open another project, the layer URL query in the legend has a fixed value and the legend does not display the symbol, only the layer title, because in that project the layer has a URL query with a dynamic variable and the legend does not "find" the corresponding layer in the project.

```
...<layer-tree-layer name="Some Name" id="query_where_obec_3D598259_text__objectIds__time__geometry__geometryType_...">
    <customproperties>
     <Option type="Map">
      <Option name="cached_name" type="QString" value="Území obce"/>
     </Option>
    </customproperties>
   </layer-tree-layer>
   <custom-order enabled="0"/>
  </layer-tree-group>...
```

**In the "ID" option i need to insert the QGIS variable.**

Is this possible or is there another solution for this problem?

EDIT: I must have **auto update turned off** for custom legend item settings.

REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE: Create a label in map composer, save as template (.qpt) and insert a qgis variable in the .qpt file somehow and after opening the template in a new map composer it should appear in the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is `labelText="[% @myvar %]"`:

```
<layer-tree-layer name="Some Name" id="[% @myvar %]">
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ad: Can this solution be applied to the layer source? I mean if I replace part of the source with a variable.

Comment: I guess. What happens if you try?

Comment: The layer in the legend is not displayed, only the label. And the layer source does not display the value of the variable, but the entire variable entry.